# String manipulation in xstring

Tags: strings, xstring

I'm trying to make a string manipulation by using xstring package.

Fore example `\myparam` equals to this: `1.1 Optimal solution of RNASP`

But string functions doesn't work. For example `\StrLeft{\myparam}{10}` gives this error: `Missing control sequence inserted. ...RNASP.\relax }}{10}{figure.caption.8}`

I set this: `\def\myparamDet{\detokenize{myparam}}`

`\myparamDet` equals to this: `\hyper@linkstart {link}{\Hy@tocdestname }{\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces Optimal solution of RNASP.\relax }}\hyper@-linkend`

After detokenize this works: `\StrLeft{\myparamDet}{10}` and result is `\hyper@lin`

So I need two things:

- Getting `1.1` from myparam and setting it to a new variable
- Removing `1.1` from myparam

Comment: With the `\detokenize`, you discover what `\myparam` *really* equals, and it is not a string, but rather a hyperlink macro with various arguments set.  Can you indicate whether the intended use will *always* be for such hyperlinks?

Comment: You really need to provide a small compiling example that highlights the issue.

Comment: Is result of detokenize not sufficient ? I suppose it is an escaped version of the hyperlink macro. Yes this manipulation will only be used for this type of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `\detokenize`, you discover what `\myparam` really equals, and it is not a string, but rather a hyperlink macro with various arguments set. So you need to set up helper macros to grab the right argument and subargument from the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\myparam{\hyper@linkstart {link}{\Hy@tocdestname }{\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces Optimal solution of RNASP.\relax }}\hyper@linkend}
\newcommand\getmystring[1]{\expandafter\argfouroffive#1}
\newcommand\argfouroffive[5]{\xdef\NL{\argtwoofthree#4}\xdef\Mys{\argthreeofthree#4}}
\newcommand\argtwoofthree[3]{#2}
\newcommand\argthreeofthree[3]{#3}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\getmystring\myparam

Number is \NL

String is \Mys
\end{document}
```

[image]